# Space of continuous paths up to strict reparametrization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Take a Hausdorff topological space $X$. Take two distinct points $x$ and $y$ of $X$. Consider a set $U$ of continuous paths $p$ from $[0,1]$ to $X$ equipped with the compact-open topology such that: $p(0)=x$, $p(1)=y$, $p$ is one-to-one and such that if $p\in U$, then $p\phi\in U$ for any nondecreasing homeomorphism $\phi:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ (let us call this group $G$).

> Is the map $U\to U/G$ always a weak homotopy equivalence ? Or could someone
> provide a counterexample ?

I know cases where it is true. I am unsure that it is true in full generality and I'd be interested in seeing a counterexample.

Note: in fact, I work with $\Delta$-Hausdorff $\Delta$-generated spaces $X$ ($\Delta$-Hausdorff meaning that any continuous map $[0,1]\to X$ has a closed image), but I do not think that it is relevant here.

Comment: I do not understand your question: to define $X/G$, you would need to give an action of $G$ on $X$. Do you mean $U/G$?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Yes I have edited my question.

Comment: Let's consider the case where $X$ is compact.  Given $p\in U$, we know that $p\:[0,1]\to p([0,1])$ is a homeomorphism so we can apply the Tietze Extension Theorem to $p^{-1}$ to give $u\colon X\to [0,1]$ with $u\circ p=1$.  We can then put $F=\{q\in U:u\circ q\text{ is injective }\}$ and $F_1=\{q\in U:u\circ q=1\}$ and we find that $F=G\times F_1$.  I think that $F$ is closed in $U$ with empty interior so it is not clear whether this is useful.